# Google App Script IF function checking only one row, and applying the result to all rows

Tags: if-statement, google-apps-script

I seem to be going quite wrong somewhere.

I'm writing a script that will automatically send out a reminder email if a Google sheet cell turns to "Yes".

The problem is my script seems to read it as:
if the second row has a "yes" it will return true for all rows and send out an email to everyone, regardless of the other rows saying "yes" or "no".
if any other row has a yes, then it seems to be completely ignored.

Defining the range to check:

```
 //looping through all of the rows
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    var row = data[i];


// Creating where the if statement is check
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var thisQuarter = ss.getRange("H2:H50").getValue();
```

The IF statement to check against:

```
// checking for this quarter
if (
  thisQuarter == "Yes") {
      var subject =
        'Your BCP is due to expire this quarter: ';
      MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message,);
      Logger.log('this quarter');
    }

   

  
   
    }
  }
```

If anyone could give me a couple pointers as to where I'm going wrong, that would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you,

Comment: Is your column H2:H50 which is being checked not part of your row data `data[i]`. Based on my understanding the email details should vary depending on the row where `Yes` is found. Could you provide a complete code snippet from where your email details and your ranges? I would also appreciate if you could provide a sample sheet

Answer (score 0):

Ideally post a view only copy of the sheet. I believe the problem is this section of code:

```
// checking for this quarter
if (
  thisQuarter == "Yes") {
      var subject =
        'Your BCP is due to expire this quarter: ';
      MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message,);
      Logger.log('this quarter');
    }
```

thisQuarter is assigned here:

```
var thisQuarter = ss.getRange("H2:H50").getValue();
```

change that line to this:

```
var thisQuarter = ss.getRange("H2:H50").getValues();
```

so thisQuarter is an array of values from the range specified

change the if statement to this and see if it helps:

```
for (i = 0; i < thisQuarter.length; i++) {
   if (thisQuarter[i][0] == "Yes" {
    // send email
   }
}
```